# How can I define the order for ObjectSet?

Tags: entity-framework

The default order of ObjectSet is by identity. Is there any attribute I can use in mapping to specify the custom order? I don't want introduce any property that would order entities, instead of "EntitiesByMyOrder" property i want the certain order as default order from mappings.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason not to use the [ObjectSet.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358828.aspx) method?
There is also a set of the OrderBy extension method overloads on the [ObjectSet Members page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382816.aspx).

Comment: As I said I don't need OrderBy overrides but change in default order.
The reason is that valid order is only one order. Why I should use "OrderBy" overrides everywhere if there is only one certain order that is legal. And I want this order to be default order in mappings.

Comment: Also, In linq to sql this was kind of possible with the AssociateWith option .. eg:
 options.AssociateWith<ItemTemplate>(i => i.ItemTemplates.OrderBy(p => p.Order));